# Magento 2.4.3-p3 Load More is not working

Tags: products, product-list, magento2.4.3, frontend-error

I am trying to show products number correctly in product list, but if click Load More button, added all products

**= Before click Load More**

[image]

[image]

**= After click Load More**

[image]

---

Added Extension - Infinite Scroll

[image]

if it was working in magento2.3.4, should I update extension version?
/home/caterin1/test.cateringspares.com.au/app/code/Olegnax/InfiniteScroll/view/frontend/templates/loader.phtml

```
<?php
/**
 * @author      Olegnax
 * @package     Olegnax_InfiniteScroll
 * @copyright   Copyright (c) 2019 Olegnax (http://olegnax.com/). All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

use Olegnax\InfiniteScroll\Helper\Helper;
use Olegnax\InfiniteScroll\Model\Config\Source\LoaderType;
use Olegnax\InfiniteScroll\Model\Config\Source\Type;

/** @var Helper $_helper */
$config = $this->helper(Helper::class)->getModuleConfig('general');
if (('' !== $config['loader_type'] && Type::TYPE_DISABLED !== $config['type']) || Type::TYPE_BUTTON == $config['type']): ?>
    <script data-role="ox-infinity-scroll" type="text/x-magento-template">
        <div class="ox-product-scroll ox-product-scroll__loader--<?= $config['loader_type']; ?> ox-product-scroll__type--<?= $config['type']; ?>">
            <?php if ($config['progress_counter']): ?>
                <div class="ox-product-scroll__amount">
                    <div class="amount-wrap">
                        <?= $config['progress_label1']; ?> <span class="toolbar-number-first"></span> - <span class="toolbar-number-last"></span> <?= $config['progress_label2']; ?> <span class="toolbar-number-total"></span> <?= $config['progress_label3']; ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="amount-count-line"><span style="width: 0%;"></span></div>
                </div>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php if ('' !== $config['loader_type'] && Type::TYPE_DISABLED !== $config['type']): ?>
                <div class="ox-product-scroll__loader">
                    <?php if (LoaderType::TYPE_IMAGE == $config['loader_type']): ?>
                        <img src="<?= $this->getViewFileUrl($config['loader']) ?>"
                             class="ox-product-scroll__loader-image"/>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </div>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php if (Type::TYPE_BUTTON == $config['type']): ?>
                <div class="button ox-product-scroll__button">
                    <span class="label"><?= $config['button_label']; ?></span>
                </div>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
    </script>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The magento doesn't provide the load more function by default. And the attached codes don't relate to the load more function.
The exception.log is related to the admin.
I think you installed the one extension for the load more function.

1. Please check the extension configuration.
2. Check the extension codes.

And in default, the product numbers displayed by magento root directory/app/design/frontend/theme/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list/toolbar/amount.phtml

Comment: Thanks for your help, so I find infinite scroll extension, is right? how should I change it?

Comment: Please attach the full extension name, there are too many infinite scroll extension.
Or you can check the infinite scroll extension documentation.

Comment: if it was upgrading from magento2.3.4 to 2.4.3-p3, should I update extension version?

Comment: Yes, of course
And there are many things to do

Comment: what's mean many thing? can you explain more detail?

Comment: You have to update the server settings, the extensions, and your theme codes.
If you want to update your site, please contact to me
knightaaron838@gmail.com